# Is it possible for this sentence to happen, "I had written down what he said"

Tags: past-tense

I am Sorry but this question came across my mind when I was asking a computer question in Super User site.
Previosuly, I was writing this

> The person who will build the PC for me asked me some question about
>   something like faster Hard Disk, I don't know what exactly he meant,
>   but **I have written down what he said**, it is called SSD.

I did not jot down important notes during the conversation between the man and I, but later on, I tried to remember what he said and then I wrote down on a paper. Both the conversation and the action that I wrote the notes are already past, so I think I should use past tense and write it this way,
**"I don't know what exactly he meant, but I had written down what he said"**

But, I doubt if it is grammatically correct and if it can happen in reality, because it sounds like my writing action had finsihed before our conversation began (unless I had some kind of magical power to accurately predict someone's speech)

Thank you.

Comment: Your past-tense sentence is accurate, if you want to take that route. Also, a solid state drive is preferred. Cheers.

Comment: How about just writing "but I *wrote* down what he said"? I am trying to understand why you want to use perfect tense, since the time relationships are vague.

Comment: Kitty, check out [this question and answer.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69507/is-it-important-to-provide-additional-information-when-using-past-perfect-past) I would suggest to go with simple past: "*I don't know what exactly he meant, but I wrote down what he said*" as User3169 suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I **don't know** what exactly he meant, but I **had written down** what he said
>   I **didn't know** exactly what he meant, but I **wrote down** what he said

are both ambiguous in terms of the timing of your note taking

> I **didn't know** exactly what he meant, but ***afterwards*** I **wrote down** what he said

removes the ambiguity.